# How to get all replies to a comment?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

How do I get the replies to a Comment object? `comment.replies` only gives me an empty list.

I have already tried `r.get_submission(comment.permalink).comments`, but it just gives me one comment.

Answer (score 2):

This question was also asked on 'r/redditdev', where I  [answered it](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1x70wl/how_to_get_all_replies_to_a_comment/). Adding the link here for anyone else with the same issue.